# Pigpio Hardware PWM_unable to write frequency above 5Khz

Tags: spi, pwm, pigpio

I have been using the pigpio library as a modified spi interface to send and receive serial data. I use Chip Select, Clock, and Data Lines but i am using "bit-banging" for the timing between bits.  Using the hardware_PWM function I have had a stable clock signal at 800Hz but when I try to increase the frequency to something much faster like 5Khz I seem to have no response on the GPIO CLK pin. Could someone please explain how this function works?

I have included a part of my code and clock signal result for reference.

```
start_tick = pi1.get_current_tick()  ## starts timer 
cb1 = pi1.callback(18,pigpio.RISING_EDGE,clockstart)   ## callback function that runs clockstart once a rising edge is seen on clock pin 18.
pi1.hardware_PWM(18,800,500000)   ## uses gpio18(pin 12) as clock at 800Hz, enables clock at duty cycle 50%
```

[image]
I am using the Raspberry Pi Model 4B so I believe I should be following the steps for the BCM2711.I have included a link to pigpio documentation and I am unsure about the amount of steps they ask for.
https://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#hardware_PWM

[image: hardware_PWM Info]

Answer (score 1):

There are known problems on the Pi4B and later (the Pis with the BCM2711).

We have not discovered the reason and currently there is no known fix.

https://github.com/joan2937/pigpio/issues/517